# PHP - How user can set directory where downloaded file will be saved?

Tags: php

I am making a simple application in which the user uploads files using 2 HTML input:file fields and a zip archive is created from them. Is there any way I can let the user choose where this zip can go? (Something like a "Save As" window).

This is my current solution, which saves archive only to default download destination without asking.

```
    $files = array($_FILES["fileone"]["name"], $_FILES["filetwo"]["name"]);
    $zipname = "myarchive.zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: _"which saves archive only to default download destination without asking"_ - then you must have your _browser_ configured to do that, when it receives such a download. There is of course no way to specify this from the server side, that would be a huge security issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use headers to force download:

```
$file = 'somefile.zip';

if(!file)
{
    // File doesn't exist, output error
    die('file not found');
}
else
{
    // Set headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // Read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
}
```